# Apache Airflow giving broken DAG error cannot import __builtin__ for speedtest.py

Tags: python, airflow, speed-test

This is a weird error I'm coming across. In my Python 3.7 environment I have installed Airflow 2, `speedtest-cli` and few other things using pip and I keep seeing this error popup in the Airflow UI:

```
Broken DAG: [/env/app/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 156, in <module>
    import __builtin__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 179, in <module>
    _py3_utf8_stdout = _Py3Utf8Output(sys.stdout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 166, in __init__
    buf = FileIO(f.fileno(), 'w')
AttributeError: 'StreamLogWriter' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

For sanity checks I did run the following and saw no problems:

```sh
~# python airflow/dags/my_dag.py 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py:94 DeprecationWarning: provide_context is deprecated as of 2.0 and is no longer required

~# airflow dags list
dag_id     | filepath      | owner   | paused
===========+===============+=========+=======
my_dag | my_dag.py | rafay   | False  


~# airflow tasks list my_dag 
[2021-03-08 16:46:26,950] {dagbag.py:448} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /env/app/airflow/dags
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py:94 DeprecationWarning: provide_context is deprecated as of 2.0 and is no longer required
Start_backup
get_configs
get_targets
push_targets
```

So nothing out of the ordinary and testing each of the tasks does not cause problems either. Further running the `speedtest-cli` script independently outside of Airflow does not raise any errors either. The script goes something like this:

```py
import speedtest

def get_upload_speed():
    """
    Calculates the upload speed of the internet in using speedtest api

    Returns:
        Returns upload speed in Mbps
    """

    try:
        s = speedtest.Speedtest()
        upload = s.upload()
    except speedtest.SpeedtestException as e:
        raise AirflowException("Failed to check network bandwidth make sure internet is available.\nException: {}".format(e))

    return round(upload / (1024**2), 2)
```

I even went to the exact line of `speedtest.py` as mentioned Broken DAG error, line 156, it seems fine and runs fine when I put in in the python interpreter.

```
try:
    import __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import builtins
    from io import TextIOWrapper, FileIO
```

So, how do I diagnose this? Seems like a package import problem of some sort

Edit: If it helps here is my directory and import structure for `my_dag.py`

```
- airflow
  - dags
    - tasks
      - get_configs.py
      - get_taargets.py
      - push_targets.py  (speedtest is imported here)
    - my_dag.py
```

The import sequence of tasks in the dag file are as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta
# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG
# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from tasks.get_configs import get_configs
from tasks.get_targets import get_targets
from tasks.push_targets import push_targets

...
```

Comment: Is that the *entire* error message? I doubt it - there should be more. It looks like you cut it off early.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Added the full error, but the one originally stated is the main one, others derive from it

Comment: "but the one originally stated is the main one" - it might look that way, but it's not. It's actually completely expected behavior. That part of the error message is just the Python 2 code path failing and triggering the Python 3 code path. The part afterward is stuff *actually* going wrong.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Are you sure that this is the error: AttributeError: 'StreamLogWriter' object has no attribute 'fileno'. Plus as I stated, the python speedtest lib is working fine standalone in the same environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Airflow [`StreamLogWriter`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.1.2/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py#L71) (and other log-related facilities) do not implement the `fileno` method expected by "standard" Python (I/O) log facility clients (confirmed by a [`todo` comment](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.1.2/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py#L70)). The problem here happens also when enabling the [`faulthandler` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) in an Airflow task.

So what to do at this point? Aside opening an issue or sending a PR to Airflow, it is really case by case. In the `speedtest-cli` situation, it may be necessary to isolate the function calling `fileno`, and try to "replace" it (e.g. forking the library, changing the function if it can be isolated and injected, perhaps choosing a configuration that does not use that part of the code).

In my particular case, there is no way to bypass the code, and a fork was the most straightforward method.

Comment: I ended up just chucking out python speedtest client and going with ookla's speedtest-cli which is basically just a binary I can call from anywhere.
https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli